# jquery.couchdb.js Ajax success/error not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, couchdb

I'm using jquery.couchdb.js to query my CouchDB database.  The view I want to query has both map and reduce functions within.  When sending the basic query as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   view_name = db_name+'/jobs_by_mod_stat'
   options = {'group': 'true' , 'reduce': 'true' };

   mod_stat = {};

   $db.view(view_name , {
     success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        for (i in data.rows) {
           console.log(data.rows[i].value);
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('Error loading from database: ' + e);
    }
  });

});
```

I see a sensible log for the data, indicating the query has been successful.  However, changing the line:

```
   $db.view(view_name , {
```

To

```
   $db.view(view_name , options, {
```

I don't get a success outcome from the Ajax query, but an error message is not shown either.  Firebug shows the query being sent, and the JSON data returned looks sensible:

> {"rows":[
>   {"key":["template","completed"],"value":2},
>   {"key":["template","running"],"value":2},
>   {"key":["template","waiting"],"value":6}
>   ]}

But the success function is not entered.  Any ideas why I'm seeing this behaviour, I did wonder if it's a bug in jquery.couch.js (I have couchdb 1.1.0).

Cheers.

Comment: (I know it isn't the reduce function not working - in Futon the reduce function works as expected)

Comment: Argh, figured it out!  The options being sent to Ajax in the query do not come in the 

      $db.view(view_name , options, {

line, rather they are placed after the Ajax outcome statements:

        error: function(e) {
          alert('Error loading from database: ' + e);
        },
        group: true, 
        reduce: true
       });

To a someone new to jquery and jquery.couch this doesn't seem to be particularly obvious or well documented.

Comment: Glad that you fixed this problem. Would you please write an answer and mark it accepted, so others who have a similar problem might notice the error quickly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a bit of trouble myself with the list function, until I went and looked through the source code of jquery.couch.js (the online documentation I found at http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/ seems to be outdated).

Basically, the parameters for `view` and `list` are different, the list having an extra parameter for the options, instead of having everything under the same parameter as with views.

View:

```
$.couch.db('yourdb').view('couchapp/' + viewName, {
    keys: ['keys here'],
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

List:

```
$.couch.db('yourdb').list('couchapp/' + listName, viewName, {
    keys: ['keys here']
}, {

    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```